# Overflow on bitfield for signed underlying type enum

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, bit-fields

This is for C++11 only:

If I have a regular enum like below:

```
enum TestType
{
Test0 = 0,
Test1,
Test2,
Test3,
Test4,
Test5,
Test6,
Test7
}
```

and a packed struct like this:

```
struct
{
TestType a : 3
uint32_t b : 5
} TestStruct;
```

Is `TestStruct.a` guaranteed to be equal to any valid assigned enum value when accessed?  Or is there a possibility the compiler will assign a signed underlying type and then treat the bitfield `a` as ranging -4 to 3.

Comment: _"... assigned enum value?..."_  What value, `TestStruct` is has not been initialised..

Comment: The smallest underlying type you could have for this is (u)int8_t so I dont think it would change anything since your values go from 0-7. You cant have a range of -4,3 because the enum's underlying type is not affected by the bitfield.

Comment: From cppreference on BitFields "Whether char, short, int, long, and long long bit fields that aren't explicitly signed or unsigned are signed or unsigned.  
 For example, int b:3; may have the range of values 0..7 or -4..3. "  So if the compiler chose the underlying type to be int8_t, then there is a possibility that the bitfield could only contain values from -4 to 3, which would result in Test4 and above to overflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is `TestStruct.a` guaranteed to be equal to its assigned enum value?

No.  You default initialize `TestStruct`.  If this is in the global space then it will be zero initialized and `a` and `b` will both be 0.

If this is in block space then no initialization happens which means `a` and `b` have an unspecified value.  All you know is that the value will be in the representable range for the type.  `Test0` having a value of `0` does not com into play here at all.

If you had

```
TestStruct{};
```

Then `a` and `b` would be zero as you are value initializing the object and in this case that means you zero initialize it.  You could also use

```
TestStruct{value1, value2};
```

to assign specific values to `a` and `b`.

---

For the question on if `a` can store all of the values of `TestType` we have to look at [[class.bit]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.bit#4) which states

> [...]If the value of an enumerator is stored into a bit-field of the same enumeration type and the **number of bits in the bit-field is large enough to hold all the values** of that enumeration type ([dcl.enum]), the original enumerator value and the value of the bit-field shall compare equal.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

and the values of the enumeration is defined by [[dcl.enum]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.enum#8) as

> For an enumeration whose underlying type is fixed, the values of the enumeration are the values of the underlying type. Otherwise, for an enumeration where e<sub>min</sub> is the smallest enumerator and e<sub>max</sub>
>    is the largest, the values of the enumeration are the values in the range 
>   b<sub>min</sub> to b<sub>max</sub>, defined as follows: Let K be 1 for a two's complement representation and `0` for a ones' complement or sign-magnitude representation. b<sub>max</sub> is the smallest value greater than or equal to max(|e<sub>min</sub> − K, |e<sub>max</sub>|) and equal to 2<sup>M</sup>−1, where M is a non-negative integer. b<sub>min</sub> is zero if e<sub>min</sub> is non-negative and −(b<sub>max</sub>+K) otherwise. The size of the smallest bit-field large enough to hold all the values of the enumeration type is max(M,1) if b<sub>min</sub> is zero and M+1 otherwise. It is possible to define an enumeration that has values not defined by any of its enumerators. If the enumerator-list is empty, the values of the enumeration are as if the enumeration had a single enumerator with value 0

So in this case e<sub>min</sub> is 0 and e<sub>max</sub> 7 so b<sub>min</sub> is 0 and b<sub>max</sub> is equal to or greater than max(|e<sub>min</sub>| − K, |e<sub>max</sub>|) which is 7. Since it has to be equal to 2<sup>M</sup>−1 if we use 3 for M then we also get 7.

We have

> The size of the smallest bit-field large enough to hold all the values of the enumeration type is max(M,1) if b<sub>min</sub> is zero and M+1 otherwise.

and b<sub>min</sub> is zero so the smallest bitfield we need is 3 which you have so you are guaranteed that all of the values of `TestType` will fit in `a`.

Comment: It also depends on the scope where `TestStruct` is defined. At namespace scope, `TestStruct.a` will be zero. Anyway, the question seems to be about the underlying type of the enum, and if it's signed, is it OK to have it represented by a 3 bit bitfield.

Comment: @Praetorian I've updated the answer to include that.  I forgot it about globals being zero initialized.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't referring to what the value is after initialization.  I was asking if any assignment (initializer, value assignment, etc) to any of the valid enum values is guaranteed to result in the same value when the bitfield is accessed.

Comment: "*All you know is that the value will be in the representable range for the type.*". The value is indeterminate and using it, undefined behavior.

Comment: @NathanOliver Second half is what I was looking for and sounds correct, I'm marking answer accepted.  Thanks for the insight.